# How to force user to re-launch app after changing language

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

**The scenario is following:**
Working on a project that enables the user to select their preferred language using a dropdown.

```
- (IBAction)languageBtnPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

I was planning to force the user to exit the app using exit(0) with a prompt of course. So that the localizable strings could be loaded. How do I automatically relaunch the app? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `exit(0)` will make your app not pass the review, and there's no way to programatically restart the app. Why not reload the texts without restarting the app?

Comment: No, don't do it. Your app will be reject by Apple. You can support multi-language within your app.

Comment: @QuocNguyen it won't I uploaded a similar app

Comment: @Sh_Khan there is no mention of it in App Store Review Guidelines, but Human Interface Guidelines explicitly say not to quit programmatically (or at least they used to)

Comment: @mag_zbc Also i saw a lot of apps do it without rejection , sure it's not recommeded to do it but changing language without restart won't change base localization which makes the app inconsistent

Comment: I was hoping to do it something like the way ClashRoyale does it, the implementation is really clean, you get a user confimation prompt after that the App restarts to the launch screen and it immediately gets localized.

Answer (score 0):

You can't relaunch the app in IOS , the user already has the experience to relaunch it himself

Answer (score 0):

I have this code:

```
- (void)changeLanguage:(NSString *)newLang {
    [NSBundle setLanguage:newLang];
    [self reloadViewController];
}
```

**Where in NSBundle:**

```
@implementation NSBundle (Language)

+ (void)setLanguage:(NSString *)language
{
    //if language not supported we default to spanish
    if (language == nil || ![SMLocalizedString isLanguageSupported:language]){
        //defaults to spanish
        language = @"es";
    }

    //Sotres new language setting in user 
    [SMLocalizedString updateCurrentLanguage:language];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle], [BundleEx class]);
    });

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:language, nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    id value = language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil;
    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &kBundleKey, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

**And then, I reload my View Controller:**

```
- (void)reloadViewController {
    SMAppDelegate *delegate = (SMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIStoryboard *storybaord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainIpad" bundle:nil];
    delegate.window.rootViewController = [storybaord instantiateInitialViewController];
}
```

Comment: what is a SMLocalized string? are you using any external frameworks or libraries? can't find anything from google "SMLocalized string"

Comment: SMLocalizedString is a class I have for updating my language: only changes a parameter.